# Readability practices for capturing a large number of keycodes in an event handler?

Tags: javascript, angular

*This is more of a pure JS question, but I'm also tagging with Angular2 in case an Angular developer has any ng2 techniques to accomplish this*

I'm writing an angular2 application and am writing a `keydown` event handler to trap a large number of keycodes being used in a *contentEditable* `span`.

```
<span [contentEditable]="true" (keydown)=keydown($event)>
  {{myDate}}
</span>
```

(non-Angular folks: that's just shorthand for registering a `keydown` event handler)

The event handler code becomes hard to read:

```
keydown = ($event:KeyboardEvent) =>{
  let key = $event.keyCode;
  if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && key != 191 && key != 189 && key != 220 && key != 8 && key != 46 && key != 9){ // 0-9, plus -_\/| as delimiters, plus backspace/delete/tab
    $event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

This totally works, but the readability degrades and it begins to look like code I "got away with" as a student.

Splitting it into multiple lines and commenting each keycode looks a bit better:

```
keydown = ($event:KeyboardEvent) =>{
  let key = $event.keyCode;
  if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && // 0-9
    key != 191 && // /
    key != 189 && // -
    key != 220 && // \
    key != 8 && // backspace
    key != 46 && // delete
    key != 9){ // tab
    $event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

But in C# you could do something like this to reduce the number of boolean operators:

```
if ({'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '/', '\\', Keys.Tab, Keys.Delete, Keys.Backspace}.Contains($event.keyCode){
  $event.preventDefault();
}
```

Are there any best practices for writing clean code that checks a lot of keycodes? Am I just being gun shy about writing long conditional expressions in JavaScript?

Comment: In JS you can also use `Array.prototype.includes`

Comment: Did you try to challenge StackOverflow about how many backticks it can take? ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important part is always expressiveness. Terseness is only relevant in competitions about how to write something in C ;-)

```
isDigitKey(keyCode:number):boolean {
  return key >=49 && <= 57;
}

isDelimiterKey(keyCode:number):boolan {
  switch(keyCode) {
    case 189: // dash
    case 191: // slash
    case 220: // backslash
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

isEditKey(keyCode:number):boolan {
  switch(keyCode) {
    case 8: // backspace
    case 9: // tab
    case 46: // delete
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

isValidKey(keyCode:number):boolean {
  return this.isDigitKey(key) || this.isOperatorKey(key) || this.isEditKey(key)
}

keydown = ($event:KeyboardEvent) =>{
  let key = $event.keyCode;
  if (!(this.isDigitKey(key) || this.isOperatorKey(key) || this.isEditKey(key)) {
    $event.preventDefault();
  }

  // alternative
  if (!this.isValidKey(key)) {
    $event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: This turned out to be *exactly* what I needed, thank you! Though Ha Doan's answer above has the succinctness I wanted, I now realized I also need to handle several combinations of ctrl/alt/shift modifiers as well, and your solution makes that *far* more readable!

Answer (score 2):

You can pre-define an array of keycodes as below:

```
    var keyCodes = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '/', '\\'];
    if (keyCodes.find(predicate) === $event.keyCode) {
        // do something
    }

function predicate(e) {
    return e === $event.keyCode;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```ts
if ([48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 191, 189, 220, 8, 46, 9].indexOf(key) === -1) 
{
  $event.preventDefault();
}
```

---

### Simple JS Demo:

```js
var keydown = function(event){
  var key = event.keyCode;
    
  if ([48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 191, 189, 220, 8, 46, 9].indexOf(key) === -1){
    document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'Prevent: ' + key;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'DoNothing: ' + key;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<input type="text" onkeydown="keydown(event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

In js you have to create helper function, there is not way to create map/object like it is done in C#:

```
//somewhere in the outer code:
this.keymap = convert([1, 2, 3, 4]);

//handler
if (this.keymap[event.key]) {
    //bla-bla
}

function convert(keys) {
    var map = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) { 
        map[keys[i]] = true;
    }
    return map;
}
```